# Recursion with strings

Tags: c, recursion

i need to write a recursion function thats gets a string and then print only letters (captial & small) from the end to start

```
for exemple:
str={"abc123#@!456DEF&^65gHj"}
Reducing(str);
output: jHgFEDcba .
```

but im stuck on the part of how to get the function go on to the next char
all i can do is print the last char and thats it im stuck... please help

```
here's my code:

void Reducing(char str[])
{
    if (str[0] == '\0')
        return ;

    if ((str[strlen(str)-1] <= 122 && str[strlen(str)-1] >= 97) || (str[strlen(str)-1] <= 90 && str[strlen(str)-1] >= 65))
        putchar(str[strlen(str)-1]);

    Reducing(str+(strlen(str)));
}
```

Comment: Can you make a simpler version, which is just reversing the string as is? Then modify it to filter. And hint: It should *not* be tail recursion (well, it can, but you loose the point).

Comment: Don't attempt to compute `strlen` on each iteration. Just move one character up on each iteration, then unwind.

Comment: Using `isalpha()` would be cleaner and remove the magic numbers.

Comment: i dont understand you how to move one char????

Comment: I suggest you to try [Robozzle](http://www.robozzle.com/) :) It makes a heavy usage of head recursion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using just `str[0]` instead of `str[strlen(str) - 1]` and pass `str + 1` for the recursion:

```
void Reducing(char str[])
{
    if (str[0] == '\0')
        return ;

    if ((str[0] <= 122 && str[0] >= 97) ||
            (str[0] <= 90 && str[0] >= 65))
        putchar(str[0]);

    Reducing(str + 1);
}
```

Comment: thats whats i did at first try but it prints frim start to end and i want it to do the opposite, thats why i try to use the  "str[strlen(str)-1]"

Comment: @monkey.D.Ganga Change the order of the function then

Comment: goddamn im so noob that i dident think about it thanks alot it works!! and now i know what i did worng and how to fix it next time =)

Answer (score 4):

I believe the whole point of the exercise is to move down the string one character per recursive step, until you hit the end, and then print the current character on the way back (after the recursive call).  You are not supposed to use `strlen`.

A string is a sequence of characters in memory terminated by a zero (or NUL) character.  Providing the address of the first character in the string allows you to find all of the other characters by adding an offset to the address.  A string can also be thought of like a snake with a head (the first character), and a tail (the remaining characters).  The head is the single character located at the address of the string. 
The tail is the string located at the address plus 1.

In order to print a string backwards, if the string is empty (its head is NUL), then we don't have to do anything.  Otherwise, if we print the tail backwards by recursively calling the backwards print function, and then print the head character, then we accomplish our goal.

Comment: so how am i supposed to move down the string one char??

Comment: @pat. I deleted my answer. OP needs a walking lesson, not a fishing lesson.

Comment: `str` is a pointer to a contiguous array of characters in memory.  Granted, it is declared as an array, but as an argument to a function, it is really a pointer.  You could change the type from `char[]` to `char*` to make it more obvious.

Comment: i dont understand you guys please be easy with me im new in that

Comment: @monkey.D.Ganga You need to know a basic terminology in order to properly communicate this stuff. If you don't have it you might need to make few steps back.

Comment: @Mad Physicist, no problem.  I've been known to post full answers to similar questions in the past, and been called out!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the interface you typically use to take a string to read from it is:

`void reducing(const char*);`

The const is important here if you want to call your function on string literals (which you typically want).

Second, the c standard library provides functions such as `isalpha()` in the [`ctype`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/ctype_h.htm) header to check if a char belongs to certain standard categories.

And last but not least, what you really want to do is look at the next character, so advance the pointer by one and call yourself again until you read a `'\0'`.